# Saving scraped data on the memory

Tags: python, pandas, ods

I am scraping ods data from a website and analysing this data. I used to use pandas and odfpy to read the data from the online source, but this way lead (for unknown reason) to a very long calc time. Therefore, I tried using pandas-ods-reader to read the data after saving a sample on my local drive, and it was more efficient in reading the data. However, pandas-ods-reader seems to be not able to read data existing on the internet like pandas and it can only deal with actual data saved somewhere on the local drive.

This works fine when using pandas

```
url= 'https://www.opendatani.gov.uk/dataset/be060ba2-19b1-426c-9736-94897e290bb4/resource/968cbade-736d-4d89-ae82-e54e68c31ea6/download/2019-northern-ireland-traffic-count-data.ods'

data_range=pd.read_excel(url)
```

and when I use the same URL with pandas-ods-reader, the data can't be read

```
from pandas_ods_reader import read_ods

url='https://www.opendatani.gov.uk/dataset/be060ba2-19b1-426c-9736-94897e290bb4/resource/968cbade-736d-4d89-ae82-e54e68c31ea6/download/2019-northern-ireland-traffic-count-data.ods'

data_range=read_ods(url)
```

when I run the later script I get the following error: "Unknown filetype."

I am wondering if there is a way to save the data on the RAM and call it from there in the using read_ods?

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this issue by saving the ods file on your computer.

```
import requests
from pandas_ods_reader import read_ods


url = "your_url"

response = requests.get(url)

with open("file_name.ods", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)

data_range=read_ods("file_name.ods")
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when reading line6: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'content'